# JMHTest ERROR: Unable to find the resource: /META-INF/BenchmarkList

Tags: jmh

use Jmh occur [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwIm7.png)

even though i change pom
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjKSf.png)

Comment: Please post the code or error in question, not an image.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should move annotation processor to `maven-compiler-plugin`:

```xml
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <annotationProcessorPath>
                            <groupId>org.openjdk.jmh</groupId>
                            <artifactId>jmh-generator-annprocess</artifactId>
                            <version>${jmh.version}</version>
                        </annotationProcessorPath>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

Then if you build the project with IDE you should add annotation processor in IntelliJ settings.

Also I'd upgrade the version of JMH from 1.28 to the latest 1.35.